# Ajax modal popup extender in ASP.NET webforms application

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have modal popup extender in my ASP.NET webforms application. Can I reuse the same modal popup extender in all webforms to accomplish common search?

If possible where can I place the modal popup extender? Anyone help me please

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTarget" Style="display: none;" />
            <cc1:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" ID="mp1" PopupControlID="SearchPanel" TargetControlID="btnTarget"
                CancelControlID="ImgBtnCloseSearch" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
            </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>

            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PanelSearch" OnLoad="PanelSearch_Load">
                <div id="SearchPanel" runat="server" class="modalPopup">
                    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/CloseButton.png" ID="ImgBtnCloseSearch" CssClass="Modal-Close" />
                    <div class="row">
                        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center; margin-top: 12px;">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Search Text" ID="lblKey" Style="margin-left: 5px;"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtKey" Style="margin-left: 5px;" Width="200" Height="25"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:Button Text="Go" runat="server" CssClass="Btn-Go" ID="BtnGoSearch" OnClick="BtnGoSearch_Click" Height="26" />
                            <br />
                            <div class="Div-DisplaySearchGrid">
                                <asp:GridView ID="GrdDataSearch" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GrdDataSearch_RowDataBound"
                                    Font-Size="11px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#c8c8c8" FooterStyle-BackColor="#f0f1f3" BackColor="whitesmoke"
                                    DataKeyNames="PK" BorderColor="black" CellPadding="3" ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
                                </asp:GridView>
                                <%--   <asp:GridView ID="GvSearchData" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="11px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#c8c8c8" FooterStyle-BackColor="#f0f1f3" BackColor="whitesmoke" DataKeyNames="PK" BorderColor="black"
                                    EmptyDataText="No rows to display"
                                    CellPadding="3" ShowFooter="True" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="GvSearchData_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GvSearchData_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GvSearchData_SelectedIndexChanged" Style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 2px; margin-right: 2px;">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" HeaderStyle-Width="40" Visible="false" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" HeaderStyle-Width="120" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-Width="280" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" HeaderStyle-Width="200" />
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategory" HeaderText="SubCategory" HeaderStyle-Width="200" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>--%>
                            </div>
                            <br />

                        </div>
                        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnSearchFlag" />
                       
                    </div>
                </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding it as a user control then declaring the control on the pages where you need.